# Удалить подгруженный документ из браузера

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

у меня есть Ajax запрос, пишу на JavaScript, запрос приходит в формате строки, этот скрипт формируется на стороне сервера. После выполнения скрипта подгруженный файл остается в браузере и получается любой человек может его посмотреть. Как удалить файл из браузера сразу после подгрузки? Или может ему можно установить время жизни? Вообщем не понимаю как убрать оттуда этот файл

Comment: Вопрос слишком не понятный.

Comment: Никак. Если вы кому-то что-то передали, автоматически считайте, что это что-то осталось у этого кого-то навсегда

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. В JavaScript пишете в переменную получил ли пользователь файл.
2. Через JavaScript добавляете cookie.
3. Отдача данных от PHP только при наличии этого cookie, иначе выдаёте пустой ответ.

И как только пользователь получил данные, то в JavaScript-переменную пишете true и делаете повторный запрос AJAX к PHP, но на этот раз перед запросом удаляете через JavaScript cookie.

PHP без наличия этого cookie выдаёт пустой ответ.